# swift sort dictionary array based on key

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter/sort data from firebase either into a separate array or from an existing array (articleArray).
I have a key that gets saved to firebase named dateField which contains a string of the date that's selected in dd MMM yy format.
When I pull the data I want to have the data sorted so that one array equals items with the date <= to 7 days time (I have a constant that already works out the future date) and the other array to equal everything else.

I want to use this to pass the data into my tableview with section 1 = to the <= 7 days array and section 2 = the other everything else. (I think I can figure this out once I have the arrays working correctly)

code of my retrieveArticles:

```
func retrieveArticles () {

        let datedDB = Database.database().reference().child("Articles")
        datedDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

           let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>

           let date = snapshotValue["DateField"]!
           let barcode = snapshotValue["Barcode"]!
           let datedId = snapshotValue["ArticleID"]!

           let article = Articles()
           article.date = date
           article.articleCode = barcode
           article.articleID = datedId

           self.articleArray.append(article)
           self.configureTableView()
           self.articleTableView.reloadData()
        }
   }
```

Firebase database structure:

[firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95LwU.png)

Comment: If you are using core data for local storage then use NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: Hi, I'm currently only using firebase to save and fetch data. I'm still quite new to all this.

Comment: Firebase is used for cloud storage. What happens when user kills the app and reopens the app the data would be lost and again would need to wait till it is fetched from Firebase. So it is better to store what you have fetched from firebase into local storage on the device (core data / realm) which would provide a better user experience. And UI could use the local storage as the source to display your table view. That way your app would still be useful in offline mode

Comment: @Jason post a screenshot of what your data structure looks like in firebase. Also, you have some major issues in your code now.  You should not be force unwrapping optionals.

Comment: @user1046037 none of this is relevant to his question.  Not to mention, Firebase is a real time database and has a disk persistence option if needed.

Comment: @mickeyd i've update the op with a link to image of structure.

Comment: A few things; please include your actual Firebase structure as text please, no links or images. When links break, it invalidates the question for future readers. Second thing; storing dates in that format can be challenging - it's way better to store them in a standard yyyymmdd format as then they can be easily sorted by Firebase and queries can be added to keep the data fresh. You mention two arrays but there is only one in your code. Also, what is a dictionary array? It's unclear what isn't working correctly or what you are having difficulties with - can you clarify the question?